# Simple routing table question

Tags: algorithms, computer-networks, routing

I'm having difficulties understanding the solution to the following question:

> Consider the following description of a LAN:
>
> The main Internet connection is connected to our gateway router. This
>   in turn is part of the backbone network on the 65.21.1.0/24 subnet.
>   The backbone also supports two further routers SALES and RESEARCH.
>   There is one Sales subnetwork 65.21.6.0/23, and two research
>   subnetworks 65.21.100.0/24 and 65.21.200.0/26.
>
> ```
> If the Interface addresses are:   
>
> • i1–65.21.1.1
> • i2–65.21.1.2
> • i3–65.21.6.1
> • i4–65.21.1.3
> • i5–65.21.100.1
> • i6–65.21.200.1
> ```
>
> What are the routing tables for the SALES and RESEARCH routers?
>
> [image]

How is the **via** and **interface** column derived in the solution?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a homework exercise? If so, it has probably been derived with one of the methods presented in lecture or in the companion book.

Comment: The answer is already in the figure you drew. Just follow the links ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple question on the definition of routing tables. I will add a brief explanation.

Let's take the SALES router. It has two interfaces.

The interface top (65.21.1.2) is connected to the network 65.21.1.0/24.

The interface bottom (65.21.6.1) is connected to the network 65.21.6.0/23.

This can be expressed as the following routing table:

```
network          via        interface
---------------+-----------+---------
65.21.1.0/24     direct      top
65.21.6.0/24     direct      bottom
```

Now we have two research networks accessible via the router RESEARCH. This router has an ip address 65.21.1.3 on the network 65.21.1.0/24. This network is already in the routing table, so the traffic to the research networks can be routed with the following rules.

```
network          via        interface
---------------+-----------+---------
65.21.100.0/24   65.21.1.3   top
65.21.200.0/24   65.21.1.3   top
```

Finally the traffic to all other networks should be sent to the GATEWAY for further processing. Here is the final routing table.

```
network          via        interface
---------------+-----------+---------
65.21.1.0/24     direct      top
65.21.6.0/23     direct      bottom
65.21.100.0/24   65.21.1.3   top
65.21.200.0/24   65.21.1.3   top
default          65.21.1.1   top
```

The routing table for the RESEARCH router can be assembled following the same logic.